# 2D Arrays (C++) Printing Hours and voltage in three columns

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I am able to run the program alright. But the output is not clear and somehow I feel, I haven't utilized 2D arrays properly.

The program is supposed to generate voltage (between -1 and -25), display (critical if its more than -10).. plus print them for 3 hours.

i.e. 1 hour would have 10 rows, second hour would have 10 rows and third as well.

Need help to sort out the printing and utilized the 2D array. thanks,

```
//////////////////////////////////

using namespace std;
int getLowVoltage(int Min, int Max) //function to generate random voltage
{
    return ((float(rand()) / float(RAND_MAX)) * (Max - Min)) + Min;
}

int main()
{
    int minimum = -1;
    int maximum = -25;

    int hours[10][3] = {getLowVoltage(minimum,maximum)};

    for (int x = 1; x < 4; x++)
    {
        cout << "\n Hour -  " << x << endl;


        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (getLowVoltage(minimum, maximum) < -10)
            {
                cout << "\n" << getLowVoltage(minimum, maximum) << setprecision(2) << "--critical drop";
            }

            else
                 cout << "\n" << getLowVoltage(minimum, maximum) << setprecision(2);

        }

    }
    return 0;

}
/////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: Your `hours` array will have a random value in index `[0][0]` and the rest of the values will be 0. And in your actual loop, you are calling `getLowVoltage` once to compare the value, and once to print the value, but each time the returned value will be different.

Comment: fixed the callign of getlowvoltage, calling it once now.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
  std::cout << hours[i][0] << "\t" << hours[i][1] << "\t" << hours[i][2] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: somehting like this ?

Comment: for (int x = 1; x < 4; x++)
    {
    cout << "Hour - 1 " << "\t" << "Hour - 2 " << "\t" << "Hour - 3" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
               cout << hours[x][getLowVoltage(minimum, maximum)] << "\t" << hours[x][getLowVoltage(minimum, maximum)] << "\t" << hours[x][getLowVoltage(minimum, maximum)] << endl;

                if (getLowVoltage(minimum, maximum) < -10)
               {
                    cout << "\n" << setprecision(2) << "--critical drop";}
           else
                    cout << "\n" << setprecision(2);
            }
    }
    return 0;
}

Comment: why do you need an outer loop over x?

Comment: how would i output voltage for three hours?.

Comment: check my answer: hours[i][0] means, you print for i'th row zero element from that row... in other words the snippet I gave you at the top prints out a table... just try to compile it, run it and you'll see

Comment: i am still confused big time as in how would i print the random voltage for all three hours. In the loop you provided, yes it prints a table but I am super confused.

Comment: secondly, I dont know how I would pass the if else statement within that array so that 'critical drop' gets printed.

Comment: You save your random values into the array, then you print it out. Is this what you'd like to do?

Comment: yes .. random values into any array from the random function i created.. and then print them in a table layout like you mentioned above.. I am new to programming.

Comment: so first, use this loop
for(size_t x=0; x < 4; ++x){for(size_t i=0; i<10;++i){hours[i][x] = getLowVoltage(minimum, maximum);}} this fills the array. Then use the other loop to print it out

Comment: should i use if else condition while printing?

Comment: to check while printing 

if (hours[i][]) < -10)
            {
               cout << "\n" << hours[i][]<< setprecision(2) << "--critical drop";
           }

Comment: this is how my print loop is.. i dont get the critical message displayed.

 for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) //printing voltage values on screen
    {
         if ((hours[i][0] > -10)&&(hours[i][1] > -10)&&(hours[i][2] > -10))
             {
                cout << "\t" << "--critical drop" << endl;
             }

          else
            cout << hours[i][0] << "\t" << hours[i][1] << "\t" << hours[i][2] << endl;

        }

Comment: it depends on the values stored in your array... all three temperatures needs to be higher than -10 to display critical drop